# How to mute and unmute sound in Angular2?

Tags: javascript, angular, audio-player

I have a sound in my Angular project, like this:

```
introInfo() {
   this.audio.src = '../assets/sound1.wav';
   this.audio.load();
   this.audio.play();
 }

 feedbackInfo() {
   this.audio.src = '../assets/sound1.wav';
   this.audio.load();
   // auto-start
   this.audio.play();
 }
```

And I would like to be able to mute all sounds. If I click the button in my template:

```
<img class="grow" id="mute" [src]='mute' (click)="muteF()"/>
```

How could I write my function `muteF`? I would like to mute if I click the button. If I click a second time, it must perform unmute.

Comment: Did you try setting the volume to 0? something like `this.audio.volume = 0;`

Comment: Set `this.audio.muted` to `true` however you like.

Comment: @RahulSingh I don't use player yet.. I don't know if I need player just for one function

Comment: @AnnaF you are looking for something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/mattball/sVwXH/), you can make use of viewchild or viewchildren to get the all audio element or elements and then add the muted property to them to true this will solve the problem i guess

Answer (score 2):

This works for me

```
  muteF() {
    if (this.audio.volume !== 0) {
      this.audio.volume = 0;
    } else {
      this.audio.volume = 1;
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

something like this probably (unless angular has audio-specific features, for example).

#### Component

```
import { ElementRef, Inject, Injectable, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class MyService {
  @ViewChild('audio') audio: ElementRef

  constructor(/* DOCUMENT would be an option too, from @angular/platform-browser - `@Inject(DOCUMENT) private document: any` */) {}
  introInfo() {
    this.audio.nativeElement.load()
    this.audio.nativeElement.play()
  }
//...
}
```

then in the template

### template

```
<audio #audio></audio>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use **muted** property such as

```
this.audio.muted = true;
```

Works for video element as well.

Source: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/av_prop_muted.asp